# i cannot understand a method behaviour

Tags: swift

```
func mymethod(getno:Int)->(myval :Int,defaults :Int){
    return (getno,8)
 }
 print(mymethod(getno: 2))
```

the output for the above program is 
my val is 2 default is 8

ok, i can understand above program

but the below method is doubtful for me

```
func makeIncrementer() -> ((Int) -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)
```

i can't understand this line (var increment=makeIncrementer()) what's happening there ?

Is there somebody who can explain me this briefly?

Comment: Actually quite sophisticated stuff. My book teaches you, but you'll need to read several sections; might start here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_returning_function

Answer (score 1):

`makeIncrementer` returns a function that accepts an `Int` and return an `Int` , so this

```
var increment = makeIncrementer()
```

makes `increment` variable to be equal to

```
func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
  return 1 + number
}
```

so `increment(7) = addOne(7)`

You may read   [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) chapter in Swift book

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone. I found it hard to wrap my head around this when I first started as well :)

What you are seeing is "a function returning another function". Think of functions as black boxes that take stuff in and spit stuff out. Now imagine passing these around as if they were values like `10` or `"Hello"`.

`makeIncrementer` returns a function. Which function? This:

```
func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 + number
}
```

See the line `return addOne`? That is not calling the function, but returning it!

So when you assign the return value of `makeIncrementer` to `increment`:

```
var increment = makeIncrementer()
```

`increment` now has the value of `addOne`. Calling `increment` would be the same as calling `addOne`. The above line is syntactically no different from:

```
var myString = getMyString()
```

The difference is that you are working with functions instead of strings.

Now you understand why `increment(7)` is 8.

<sub>If you want to burn your brain more, try looking up currying functions.</sub>

Comment: thanks for that help ? and is it safe this lang  can i go with objective .c because i freelancer so which languages is best and give me more income ? help me @swepper

Comment: @SubhashChandru Definitely use Swift (IMO). I see that you do some Java as well, which is another reason why you should go with Swift. Swift is more similar to Java than Objective-C is. Apple is recommending Swift as well.

Comment: @SubhashChandru If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: yeah voted because i have less reputation you cannot see sir , but its recorded !!!   and do i need to learn objective c also?

Comment: @SubhashChandru Having some knowledge of Objective-C might help you understand certain situations, but it's not like you can't live without understanding them. For example, when creating Realm objects, you always need to add the `@objc dynamic` modifiers to properties. Why? Because Realm needs to make use of dynamic dispatch provided by the Objective-C runtime, which is not available in Swift. And I mean the checkmark, not the arrows :-).

Comment: no sir , i meant will it affect me in future when i apply for job

Comment: @SubhashChandru I don’t know that much about the job market, but I know it will help when the company’s code is mostly written in objective c.